# Web Browser Navigate Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application in which I am trying to make sure that my exceptions are caught correctly. I am testing to see if a file path has been moved and present the user with a MessageBox(). This is the error popup that I am currently getting:

[image]

How can I handle that exception? I want the pop up to show the follow message:

`MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Could not retrieve the Facility List. Please report this to the system administrator.", "ERROR 011", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);`

I have tried the FileNotFoundException but was unable to get it to catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which type of exception is being thrown, add a `catch` for `Exception`, then use a breakpoint in the `catch` to see the type of exception.